# Naive rule-based machine translation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, translation

In order to develop a translation system for a constructed language, I am looking for a method that is easy to implement. I turn quite naturally to algorithms based on rules encoded by an "expert".

Thus, I am looking for references (codes, explanatory documents...) about naive translation algorithms; for example those from the 60s.

**Note**: I know that the results will probably be rough.

Answer (score 0):

Looking and working with translations, use books and dictionary, and a leguaje as reference, by example from book Moby Dick:

```
"Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how
long precisely-having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to
interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see
the watery part of the world."
```

I need translate spanish text:

```
"¿Que paises forman parte del mundo?"
```

When you use a section "with statistically more words and synonyms and antonyms" in text, called "window or scope"  this section star with a direct translation word with dictionary and end section, in this example, and search same section in spanish book

```
start : call -> Llamame.  =>  end: world -> mundo
```

after processing you result is like to:

```
how many places about of the wold
```

You could find more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_machine_translation)